# regex matching in python not working properly - Overlapping matches?

Tags: python, regex, non-greedy

I am experimenting with for `regex lazy matches`.
when I tried this:

```
>>> text='<em>Hello <>World</em>'
>>> pattern3=re.compile('<.*?>')
>>> for mat in re.findall(pattern3,text):
...     print mat
... 
<em>
<>
</em>
```

It works as expected, and gives the three matches that are possible
but when I tried this:

```
>>> text="1011"
>>> pattern1=re.compile('1.*?1')
>>> for mat in re.findall(pattern1,text):
...     print mat
... 
101
```

I get only one output, but I should get `101 and 11`, why `11` is not being matched.
my `regex '1.*?1'` looks for `1` followed by zero or more of anything and a `1` again.

Comment: The short answer is because of overlapping matches. The second `1` is matched in the first match and cannot 'participate' in another match again. Try to look around for overlapping matches. I'm sure it has been asked before. For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15799332/1578604) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this for overlapping match?

```
pattern1=re.compile('(?=(1.*?1))')
```