# Regular Expression for matching word

Tags: regex

This may be very easy but for some reason i am unable to get the expression. I want to find position/index of all matching words in a given string. for example

"THIS IS AND NAND XOR NOR AATD". now, I want to find index of matching string starting with A and can have any char between A-Z but must end with T or D. So the result should look like [9,AND][14,AND][24,AAT][25,ATD]

my expression (?s)(A.[TD]) is missing the last index. Thanks in advance. I am using python.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: This is not a regex problem; one cannot count (indices or otherwise) using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do this by using a regular expression, you need a [**Positive Lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion. I replaced the dot in your regular expression with `[A-Z]` since you stated you want to match word characters.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'(?=(A[A-Z][TD]))')
>>> for m in p.finditer('THIS IS AND NAND XOR NOR AATD'):
...     print [m.start() + 1, m.group(1)]

[9, 'AND']
[14, 'AND']
[26, 'AAT']
[27, 'ATD']
```

Comment: If i change the text to "THAXAIS AND NAND XOR NOR AATD" my results are changing. my point is it should find only three char words ending with D or T.

Comment: It is working. Thank you! I plan to test the boundary conditions. Also it would be good if you can explain what "?=" is doing to the expression.

Comment: It looksahead (not consuming characters), see the provided link.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually matching words but sequences, and the problem is that you are looking at capturing overlapping sequences.

See [Overlapping regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799332/overlapping-regex-matches) for a discussion on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

first match text using:

```
/^(.*)(A[A_Z]*[TD])/g
```

then index of matched element would be length of first matched sequence!